# I created an app where the Apple pay works fine in debug mode, but there is no in production when app is in review

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, applepay

hi i have developed an app in flutter and used  pay: ^1.0.0 package for user to pay match fee if they want to enroll in it.
it works fine in simulator iPhone 13 pro max but after uploading it to app-store the review team cannot find app pay button on that specific screen.
i have already added merchant id and apple pay capabilities in Xcode.
Note: There is none any error related to Ui like Render etc.
[image: preview from app-store team apple button is not even showing]
[image: app running in simulator and apple pay works fine]

mycode

```
ApplePayButton(
            height: 50.0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100,
            paymentConfigurationAsset: 'applepay.json',
            paymentItems: _paymentItems,
            style: ApplePayButtonStyle.black,
            type: ApplePayButtonType.buy,

            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
            onPaymentResult: (value) {
              print(value);
              UserJoined(widget.ds.id, widget.model);
            },
            onError: (error) {
              _show(context);
              print(error);
            },
            loadingIndicator: const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          ),

//_ _paymentItems

final _paymentItems = [
  PaymentItem(
    label: '[90Minutes] \nTotal',
    amount: widget.model.matchfee,
    status: PaymentItemStatus.final_price,
  ),
```

Comment: Is it working using TestFlight ?

Comment: @PtitXav if its not working with apple it should work on TestFlight.

Comment: I assume you also created the payment processing certificate and using it?

Comment: Add ur code plz

Comment: yes i have created payment processing certificate and using it

Comment: @hasan here is my code

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/setting_up_your_server
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/configuring_your_environment#3179109
https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/